# Event binding in each jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using dynamically added textbox (class name is `myclass`) and need to validate all textboxs. My code is here. This coding is working for only first textbox. If i add new text box, the code is not working. I don't know how to write the event binding in each(function())

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {         
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,             
        messages: {
            required: "Required input"                  
        }
    }); 
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="TextBoxesGroup">
<div id="Div1">
<input type='text' value ='' class='myclass' />
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" name="add" id="addButton" value="Add">
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter=2;
$("#addButton").click(function() {
     var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + counter);
var texthtml = "";
texthtml += "<input type='text name='fieldname[]' class='myclass' value='' />";
newTextBoxDiv.after().html(texthtml);
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("TextBoxesGroup");
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the html code too?

Comment: can you post code you used for appending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The each function can only be applied to elements already existing in you DOM. Elements which are added later will not be affected. You need to apply `rules()` to them after they are created. Like this:

```
$("#addButton").click(function() {
     var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + counter);
     ...
     $( newTextBoxDiv ).rules( ... );
});
```

Ps: to get more readable code, try to encapsulate your functionality into functions. Like

```
function addRulesToElement( element ) {
    $( element ).rules( ... );
}
```

You can then call this function from your `each()` loop and the `#addButton` click-handler [without repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I create a rules for all textbox because textbox generate dynamically.

Comment: How are the boxes generated? Can you post the code? That is the place where you should apply your handler(s)